# How to convert string Boolean to actual Boolean using kendo-UI data source?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to convert string boolean to actual boolean, It's not converting properly.
Here is try:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                        Aggregate:true,
          qreport:{
                  aggregateSource: [
            { Name: "viewModel.i18n.QReportCountType", Value: true },
            { Name: "viewModel.i18n.QReportMinMaxType", Value: false }
        ],
            schema: {
            model: {
              fields: {
                Name: { type: "string" },
                Value: { type: "boolean" }
              }
            }
          }
          }
        });
        kendo.bind($("#demo"), viewModel);
```

Hwere is link:
https://dojo.telerik.com/eNakOgIj/13

and in console, it always a convert to string 'true' or 'falsre';
How can I get the true or false value here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting up the `value` databinding, under the hood it is calling the ObservableObject.Set method ([documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject/methods/set)). Unfortunately the only acceptable argument types for the value are Number, String, Date, and Object. Since you are trying to set the value using a type that is not supported, it is implicitly being converted to a String.

This means that you will need to convert the value back to a Boolean when you go to reference it. E.g.

```js
var aggregate = ('' + viewModel.get('Aggregate')).toLowerCase() === 'true';
console.log(aggregate);
```

Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/AqAtekaF